# How to get the span element name having the same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the name of the span element by using javascirpt and following is the code.

HTML

```
<span class="myClass" name="q1"></span>
<span class="myClass" name="q1"></span>
<span class="myClass" name="q1"></span>
```

JS

```
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
              j=1;
              for(var i=0; i < spans.length; i++){
                 alert("i value is==>"+i);                
                  spans[i].innerHTML=j;
            var obj=spans[i];
            alert("name==>"+obj.name);
                  j++;                  
              }
```

Please suggest and as name getting undefined.

Answer (score 4):

In jQuery it would be:

```
$('.myClass').each(function(){
    console.log( $(this).attr('name') )
})
```

```js
    $('.myClass').each(function(){
        console.log( $(this).attr('name') )
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="myClass" name="q1"></span>
<span class="myClass" name="q1"></span>
<span class="myClass" name="q1"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the `name` attribute of an element, you have to use `getAttribute` function.

Your solution (**ES5**):

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass"),
    j = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  alert("i value is==>" + spans[i].getAttribute('name'));
  spans[i].innerHTML = j;
  var obj = spans[i];
  alert("name==>" + obj.getAttribute('name'));
  j++;
}
```

```html
<span class="myClass" name="q1"></span>
<span class="myClass" name="q1"></span>
<span class="myClass" name="q1"></span>
```

**ES6** solution.

```js
let elems = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
Array.from(elems).forEach(v => console.log(v.getAttribute('name')));
```

```html
<span class="myClass" name="q1"></span>
<span class="myClass" name="q1"></span>
<span class="myClass" name="q1"></span>
```